# Python indentation newbie

Tags: python, indentation

Hi i am struging to get my head round indentaion levels with this code-

```
def getSolarFlowtemperature():

    #Open the temperature sensor, read it and process the result
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000003086819/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
    temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
    temperature = temperature / 1000

    #This while function checks for the error temperatures, and tries to read the sensor again to get a proper value. After 10 tries it stops
    count = 0
    while temperature == -0.062 or temperature == -0.125:
            time.sleep(2)
            count = count + 1
            print 'Temperature error on 28-000003086819, retrying'
            tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000003086819/w1_slave")
            text = tfile.read()
            tfile.close()
            temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
            temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
            temperature = temperature / 1000
    if count > 10:
    break

    else:

    return(temperature)
```

Can some one advise where the indentation is incorrect?

Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The if/else should be in the while and their code should be indented, **break does not make sense outside of a loop**

```
def getSolarFlowtemperature():
    #Open the temperature sensor, read it and process the result
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000003086819/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
    temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
    temperature = temperature / 1000

    #This while function checks for the error temperatures, and tries to read the sensor again to get a proper value. After 10 tries it stops
    count = 0
    while temperature == -0.062 or temperature == -0.125:
            time.sleep(2)
            count = count + 1
            print 'Temperature error on 28-000003086819, retrying'
            tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000003086819/w1_slave")
            text = tfile.read()
            tfile.close()
            temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
            temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
            temperature = temperature / 1000
            if count > 10:
                 break
            else:
                 return(temperature)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, would appreciate more advice regarding break making no sense where it is.  This is code i have lifted and modified for my own use as I'm a newbie:) The idea is that the function tries for 10 times to retrieve the value i believe.

Comment: Break, will break out of a loop structure and stop the iterations, so it has to be nested in a loop somehow. Here we see the break in the if in the while so the break refers to the while. If there was one more loop it would break out of the inner loop. Using break out of a loop context is not possible and it wouldn't mean anything because there would be no iteration to stop, try it you will get an error :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if count > 10:
break
else:
return(temperature)
```

if-else conditions need to be indented as well. It should be

```
if count > 10:
  break
else :
  return temperature
```

Some other notes:

`return temperature` does not need parenthesis like you have.

Also, to open a file, read it and the close it, you can just do this:

```
with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000003086819/w1_slave", "r") as tfile :
  text = tfile.read()
```

This ensures the file handle is closed even in case of exceptions. Further, I passed a second argument `r` which specifies that the file should only be opened in read-mode.

Comment: The read-only argument is unnecessary, as that is the default mode.

Comment: Thanks for this, i have made the changes you suggest.  Am i right thinking that the 2nd line of the suggested code for opening, reading and closing a file should be indented?

Comment: Yes, it should be indented

Answer (score 0):

The while block indentaion should be like this:

```
while temperature == -0.062 or temperature == -0.125:
    time.sleep(2)
    count = count + 1
    print 'Temperature error on 28-000003086819, retrying'
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000003086819/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
    temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
    temperature = temperature / 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an indentation problem in the if statement:

```
if count > 10:
    break
else:
    return(temperature)
```

A

Answer (score -1):

```
while temperature == -0.062 or temperature == -0.125:
            time.sleep(2)
            count = count + 1
            print 'Temperature error on 28-000003086819, retrying'
            tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000003086819/w1_slave")
            text = tfile.read()
            tfile.close()
            temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
            temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
            temperature = temperature / 1000
```

There is only supposed to be 4, why have you put 8 spaces? Try that! :)

EDIT: And the if statements, anything under an if: should be indented 4 spaces! same with elif and else! :)

Comment: 1 space indention is what the profs use! No seriously, python can have any-amount of white-space indention as you and your working environment like. Want 2? use 2, want 8? use 8. Nothing wrong with it.